# Date Paramter won't work in SQL for ISNULL column

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table with a date column in it.  I am currently using ISNULL to set all NULL date values to a 1/1/2001 so it looks like so.

```
Select ISNULL(DateColumn,'1/1/2001') AS DateColumn, PartNumber
From Table
Where DateColumn < '1/1/1990'
```

It seems the created date '1/1/2001' appears on any generated list , regardless of the filter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `WHERE` clause is working with the initial `DateColumn` value, befote the

```
ISNULL(DateColumn,'1/1/2001')
```

is executed.

There are several ways to fix this, one of them is to change the `where` clause like this:

```
Where ISNULL(DateColumn,'1/1/2001') < '1/1/1990'
```

I am not sure how your real situation looks like, you can firstly check for `NULL` values and then filter the result using sub-query.

Other solution will be to transform the `where` clause like this:

```
Where DateColumn < '1/1/1990' AND DateColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hoo Ha. That worked! Thanks Johnny Bravo!

I didn't want to leave out any Null values just convert them.